# Eclipse shows error for MissingCellPolicy

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am using Apache POI to read data from Excel files. I have some blank/null cells in my Excel which I want to handle using `MissingCellPolicy.RETURN_NULL_AND_BLANK`. However, Eclipse underlines `RETURN_NULL_AND_BLANK` when I hover the mouse over it and I get a pop-up saying *RETURN_NULL_AND_BLANK cannot be resolved or is not a field*

I have imported the Row.MissingCellPolicy class. Can anyone point out what needs to be done?

Comment: Adding Row.RETURN_NULL_AND_BLANK; helped me instead of adding Row.MissingCellPolicy.RETURN_NULL_AND_BLANK; or MissingCellPolicy.RETURN_NULL_AND_BLANK; and Eclipse doesn't throw error.

This is because my worksheet is XSSFSheet which returns an XSSFRow just Row and XSSFRow (or even HSSFRow for that matter) directly inherits these constants from the Row class. [link](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFRow.html)

Answer (score 3):

[MissingCellPolicy](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.poi/poi/3.9/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Row.java#Row.MissingCellPolicy) is the static nested class of the [Row](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.poi/poi/3.9/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Row.java#Row) interface. And RETURN_NULL_AND_BLANK is the static field of the ROW interface.

So you should access with:

```
Row.RETURN_NULL_AND_BLANK;
```

Or use [static import instead](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html):

```
import static org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row.MissingCellPolicy;
import static org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row.RETURN_NULL_AND_BLANK;

//....
MissingCellPolicy policy = RETURN_NULL_AND_BLANK;
```

Comment: I've never used a static import previously. Where do I use it?

Comment: Using `static import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row.MissingCellPolicy;` is throwing an error.

Answer (score 0):

Adding Row.RETURN_NULL_AND_BLANK; helped me instead of adding Row.MissingCellPolicy.RETURN_NULL_AND_BLANK; or MissingCellPolicy.RETURN_NULL_AND_BLANK; and Eclipse doesn't throw error.

This is because my worksheet is XSSFSheet which returns an XSSFRow just Row and XSSFRow (or even HSSFRow for that matter) directly inherits these constants from the Row class. [See more info here](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFRow.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
Row is interface 
MissingCellPolicy is the enum in Row
and
1. RETURN_NULL_AND_BLANK
2. RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL
3. CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK
```

is the static field
To Access any of 1 to 3

use

```
Row.MissingCellPolicy.RETURN_NULL_AND_BLANK
```

or use other two as per requirement